# File rotation using winston works unexpected

Tags: node.js, winston

I have created a [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) logger:

```
_logger.add(logger.transports.File, {
    filename: conf_fileName,
    timestamp:'true',
    maxsize: 1024,
    maxFiles: 2
});
```

But after couple of hours I have lot of files in size of ~2kb. Is there something wrong with the logger definition?

Answer (score 3):

The `maxsize` is in bytes - so you are limiting the logfiles to 1KB (which may be reported by your OS as 2KB).

If you want 1MB, try `maxsize: 1048576`

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue where `maxFiles` and `maxsize` are both set where it does not honor your `maxFiles` setting.

[See this issue on the issue tracker](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/397)